# iPhone App too large for SpringBoard to launch?

Tags: iphone

I created an iPhone app that has almost 500MB of data. But the problem is SpringBoard keeps crashing when trying to run it. It runs fine without the 500MB of data so I'm guessing I am packaging the data wrong. I placed all the files under the resources in folders. Only one piece of data is called at anytime in my program, so I don't know why SpringBoard won't run it when I see larger programs being sold on iTunes.

Answer (score 4):

But how much of that 500MB of data is your app trying to load into *memory*? The iPhone O/S will kill your app if it slurps up too much -- at any point during your app's run cycle.

Answer (score 2):

The size limit for iPhone apps is more than 500MB (pretty sure it's 2GB) so that isn't the problem.

Check all your connections in IB, and double check any warnings in Xcode that might point you towards the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I was asking the wrong question. The iPhone doesn't have any problem with the size of the file, but the number of files I was processing which is close to 100,000 files. So I must somehow place these files by placing them in a database. Thanks for the help.